# I want To expand my textField vertically by giving it a flex so that it will be responsive with all portrait screens ,but it giving me some errors

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, expand

I need Your help please I want to put my textfield in an expanded widget so that it will be expanded vertically

```
 body:Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                flex: 2,
                child: TextField(
                  expands: true,
                  maxLines: null,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: "Write Something"
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: RaisedButton(
                  child: Text("click"),
                ),
              )
            ],
          )
```

Comment: Maybe you can describe the scenario a bit more - like you want the actual textfields (areas) to fill the parent height? Maybe you can provide a mockup of what you want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

```
body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            flex: 7,
            child: TextField(
              expands: true,
              maxLines: null,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "Write Something"
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Flexible(

            fit: FlexFit.loose,
            flex: 1,
            child: RaisedButton(
              child: Text("click"),
            ),
          )
        ],
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

The error your code has is missing button `onPressed` parameter. Expanding `TextField` depends on your desire UI and can be implemented in different ways. The following is is one of them:

```
Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: TextField(
              expands: true,
              maxLines: null,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: "Write Something"
              ),
            ),
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {  },
            child: Text("click"),
          )
        ],
      )
```